# mysql, how to join this key id?

Tags: mysql

Forgive me, I am new to mysql

I have this mysql table:

```
|ID|KeyID1|KeyID2|Param|Value|...
|asdf|1|2| ...
```

The KeyID1 and KeyID2 values exist another Table like this:

```
|KeyID|Real Name|
| 1   | Gordon 
| 2   | Jason
```

I want to be able to join the two tables together such that I would have ID|Real Name1|Real Name2|Param|Value

what would i need to do in mysql? Would I need to duplicate another table?

edit: i can change the database design

Comment: missed somewhere while designing database

Comment: Are there two different tables? What are their names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic JOIN operation:

```
SELECT ID, tab1.RealName as RealName1, tab2.RealName as RealName2, Param, Value
       FROM mytable JOIN nametable AS tab1 ON (mytable.KeyID1 = tab1.KeyID)
                    JOIN nametable AS tab2 ON (mytable.KeyID2 = tab2.KeyID) ;
```

I'm assuming that your first table is called `mytable` and that the name lookup table is called `nametable`, and I also removed the spaces from column names.

Whenever you need to replace a foreign unique identifier by values from the corresponding lookup table, it's time for a JOIN on that lookup table. If you do it multiple times from the same table, you can use aliases (`AS`) to disambiguate which instance you are referring to.

Comment: never knew about the AS ability!

Comment: Hehe - `AS` is absolutely necessary when your columns are the result of some function: `SELECT MD5("Hello") AS hash;`, or `SELECT MD5(tab2.RealName) AS hash2 ...` -- otherwise you'd have a really hard time referring to the result.